# HTML/CSS - Center align text box in table row with text below

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to work out how to align text below a centered input box in a table row without the text box from being pushed up.

Here's my table:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th colspan="2">Info</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <input type="text" value="" />
            <br/> Test
            <br/> Test2
        </td>
        <th>Something</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Blah
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Blah
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Blah
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpLt72dm/) showing what I mean

I want to vertically align the text box to be centered while the text shows below it and doesn't push the box up

Comment: `td{ text-align:center;}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

Edit - This is a difficult one, you can hack it together using padding-top but it will become worse if the content grows.

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th colspan="2">Info</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" rowspan="4" style="padding-top:10%;">
            <input type="text" value="" />
         <br> asdf
          <br>asdf
     
    
        </td>
        <th>Something</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Blah
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Blah
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Blah
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry should have specified, looking to vertically align it so that the textbox says vertically center while the text goes below it and doesn't push the textbox up